# Oracle - Determine number of rows and print thereof

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to determine weather there is more than 1 row returned from a select statement. If this is false I dont want any results. I have tried the following.

```
select s.id_numeric,s.client_id,s.depth,s.fas_sample_type,s.profile_number
from sample s 
where s.client_id = upper ('128336A') 
and s.id_numeric between 12325 and 12327
and s.fas_sample_type = sample_pkg.get_soil_sample
and s.status = sample_pkg.get_authorised_sample
and s.flg_released = constant_pkg.get_true
and rownum >= 1
```

The above query only works because I have added  rownum >= 1. But once I add rownum > 1 there is no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
with base_data as (
  select s.id_numeric,
         s.client_id,
         s.depth,
         s.fas_sample_type,
         s.profile_number
  from   sample s 
  where  s.client_id = upper ('128336A') 
  and    s.id_numeric between 12325 and 12327
  and    s.fas_sample_type = sample_pkg.get_soil_sample
  and    s.status = sample_pkg.get_authorised_sample
  and    s.flg_released = constant_pkg.get_true
)
select *
from   base_data b
where  (select count(*) from base_data) > 1
```

Comment: The above query returns results when I change  and    s.id_numeric between 12325 and 12327 to utilize another field? Can you please explain this query?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand the question. It does what you asked for - returns data if there is more than 1 line.

Comment: I have used dense_rank function to tag each row based on id_numeric as per above. There are standard 12 results per an id_numeric parameter. How do I verify once a tag has changed?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `analytical function` as following:

```
Select * from
(select s.id_numeric,
         s.client_id,
         s.depth,
         s.fas_sample_type,
         s.profile_number,
         Count(1) over() as cnt
  from   sample s 
  where  s.client_id = upper ('128336A') 
  and    s.id_numeric between 12325 and 12327
  and    s.fas_sample_type = sample_pkg.get_soil_sample
  and    s.status = sample_pkg.get_authorised_sample
  and    s.flg_released = constant_pkg.get_true)
Where cnt > 1
```

Cheers!!

Comment: The above query returns results when I change  and    s.id_numeric between 12325 and 12327 to utilize another field? Can you please explain this query?

Comment: `Count(1) over()` returns number of records return by the query. So you must be getting more than 1 record when you removed `and` condition. `Analytical function` is best suitable method for your requirement. Try to execute your new query without `where cnt>1` and you will be able to understand.